# man does not find man pages associated with the source files pointed to by symbolic links

Tags: linux, gcc, osx-mavericks, manpage, ln

My hard drive recently crashed, so I took the opportunity to upgraded from Mac OS X 10.6.8 to 10.9.5 from a fresh install.  Mavericks comes with "gcc" Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51).  I want to use gcc-mp-4.8 that I downloaded from Macports.

1. So I renamed /usr/bin/gcc to /usr/bin/gcc_clang_6.0
2. In /opt/local/bin (where all the executables from Macports are installed), I created the symbolic link ... sudo ln -s gcc-mp-4.8 gcc

I can compile using the command "gcc" and save myself the extra 7 key strokes (yay!).  However, if I want to look at "man gcc", man cannot find it. I would really like to be able to view the man page without having to type "man gcc-mp-4.8"

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make an alias/function instead of changing the system compiler?  You could end up with a sad face this way.

Comment: If I 
"set alias gcc='gcc-mp-4.8' ",  "man gcc" still doesn't work.

Comment: What does the executable have to do with it? You need to link gcc-mp-4.8.1 as gcc.1 (there may be .gz at the end), somewhere in a directory named man1/, under share/.

Answer (score 1):

Previously, I did not understand how and where man pages are stored.  So for instance you can type `man -w gcc-mp-4.8`, so to symbolically link them, I used `sudo ln -s $(man -w gcc-mp-4.8) /opt/local/man/man1/gcc.1.gz`.